# How to fill rectangles depending on an item in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, generator

So basically, I need to generate an array of 1's and 0's, then fill a set amount of rectangles. The rectangles are "squares" and are required to form a bigger square. Say, I want my big square to be 500 pixels wide and high, and have it filled with 100 squares, so I need an 10 arrays with length 10 -which i partially have succeeded- and then i need to fill the small squares depending on the index of the arrays generated, like, square 1-1 should be filled if array 1-1 is 1, and so on.

```
public void run() {
    int tableSize = readInt("Enter the size of the table in pixels: ");
    int squareNumber = readInt("Enter the number of squares in a row: ");
    filler(arrayGen(squareNumber), tableSize, squareNumber);
    }

private double[] arrayGen(int A) {
    double[] arr1 = new double[A];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        arr1[i] = (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1);
    }
    return arr1;
}

private void filler(double[] A, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < x; x1+=(x/y)) {
            GRect rect1 = new GRect (x1, 0, x/y, x/y);
            rect1.setFilled(true);
            rect1.setFillColor(Color.blue);
            if (A[i] == 1) {
                add(rect1);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is what i have came up with, its still missing the some parts, namely how the following lines will be generated but like i stated above, my main issue is with the arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the main issue with the array's; I can't really tell. I can say the generation if it/them appears to be unnecessary so maybe dump that idea. Also, I wouldn't spend the resources instantiating a GRect if you're not sure it'll be added. Check if it should first; then create it, then add it.

Comment: The problem with the arrays is that in the **filler**, the program reads only the first item in the arrays and decides all rectangles that are going to be added will be filled/empty

Comment: So are *all* the rectangles to be *added* but only those with an array value of `1` is filled?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have no idea how to do that

Comment: I answered it but erased it. I think looking at Eran's answer can get you on your way. The code in my answer got you to where a *single* line of rectangles were printed correctly filled but you desire to have more than a single array so the second you add that it'll make my code obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no relation between A[i] and the i'th square. `filler` runs the outer loop `A.length` times, and the rectangles created in the inner loop all use the same `A[i]` value to determine if they should be filled, so whether they are all filled or all empty depends on the last value in the `A` array.

It also look like your `filler` method only creates rectangles for the first row of the big square.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the values of the array, now i just need to make it repeat for as many rows as there are columns ^^